# How to create a SQL date range query where the date range depends on holidays and weekends?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I would like fetch all records in Postgres that match a particular date range. The column 'date' is of type Date.

- Return all rows where date is tomorrow's date
- If today is a Friday, fetch rows that are Saturday, Sunday and Monday
- If Monday is a holiday (ex: July 4), on Friday (7/1), we will fetch transactions for Saturday (7/2), Sunday (7/3), Monday (7/4) and Tuesday (7/5)

There may be multiple holidays in tandem and the logic needs to take that into account. Assume the holidays are all available as an array of dates.

My current solution is to blindly fetch all rows that match tomorrow, and then using code (the app is Ruby on Rails) perform the above logic and look ahead if necessary.

Is there an elegant SQL solution to the above problem?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Usually calendar table can help with such scenarios

Comment: You should really focus on one single problem instead of baking three very different questions into one. Getting records from the same day can by done by using `WHERE date_trunc(column_name, 'day') = date_trunc(?, 'day')`. Getting records for a given days of the week can be done with `SELECT * FROM foos  WHERE to_char(countries.created_at, 'ID')::int IN (1, 6, 7)`.

Comment: "If Monday is a holiday". Yeah - thats a tough cookie. What is considered a holiday is completely locale dependent and will even change over time as politicians seem to have nothing better to do then to shuffle them arround. There are entire APIs for this.

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to create array of dates to fetch in ruby, as you should be you are doing that already right now to figure out if you need to fetch anything else after tomorrow, you should be able to call something like this:

```rb
array_of_dates = [Date.new(2022, 4, 30), Date.new(2022, 5, 1), Date.new(2022, 5, 2)]

MyModel.where(date: array_of_dates).order(:date)
```

That should be enough. It gets translated to SQL like this:

```sql
select * from my_models 
  where date IN ('2022-04-30', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-02') 
  order by date
```

Order is not necessary.